# Site Directory SEO

Tags: web, bing, seo

There might not be a right answer, so opinions are welcomed.

My site has a section for a product catalog `/catalog` and products are listed in that directory `/catalog/product-name`.  Should associated files and images be visible as a sub-directory (`/catalog/product-name/image/img1.png`), in the same directory (`/catalog/product-name/img1.png`), or in a central directory (`/images/img1.png`)?

This is entirely for the sake of SEO structure since the images are stored as blobs in RAM and accessed using a Hash table.

Also, my initial goal was to allow the same image to be accessed using a multitude of names (ex: `product-name-profile-shot.png` would be an alias for `img1.png`), but with there being no form of canonical linking for images, do I run the risk of looking spammy if the same image appears in multiple locations with different urls?

Comment: In the end, I decided to access all the resources from a central directory, and I am using single image names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experience, URL structure really plays an important role in internet marketing. Structured data categorized based on theme are really helpful while you optimize your website for organic search. You can refer this simple static website that is organized in same way you mentioned [yogacurious.com](http://www.yogacurious.com), just check categorization and its presence in Google search. User friendly categorization can result in better search presence !!

Regarding to image alias, i will not prefer to go for it. I recommend using same image with different alt tag by considering content and product page on which you are placing the link.

All the best

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely do not need to alter the url structure of resources. URL structure of pages is important. Resource url structure is not, and will not affect SEO.

I wouldn't create aliases for images since there is no justification for doing so from an SEO perspective.